# Making a universal bundle in Mac OS

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, architecture, bundle

I have a project whose target is a `Bundle` . Now I need to make this bundle universal for all architectures. Now I refered [this](http://meandmark.com/xcodetips.html) and this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350107/how-to-compile-universal-libraries-on-mac-os-x)

The post  says that Xcode 3.2 automatically makes the targets universal in `Release` mode

But it doesn't seem to work . I am using Xcode 3.2.6 and my Operating System is MAC OS X 10.6.8 . Can anyone please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved :

You just need to add the 3 architectures :

1)ppc

2)i86

3) x86_64

under the active architectures of the target

Comment: Probably, you will have to also set "Build Active Architecture Only" (-ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH) to No. As I see, only settings available are "Architecure" (-ARCHS) and "Valid Architectures" (-VALID_ARCHS), no property named active architecure (it is something that xcode will decide based on the build machine, I think.)