# CMake + Xcode: how to select arm64 vs x86_64 libraries?

Tags: xcode, cmake, apple-m1, fat-binaries

We have a CMake based project targeting Xcode, and must include a precompiled 3rd party library which supplies separate `arm64` and `x86_64` binaries.

What we have working now is to simply attach both binaries like

```
add_library( someLib INTERFACE )

add_library( someLib_x64 STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties(
  someLib_x64
  PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE "path/to/x64/libsomeLib.a"
)

add_library( someLib_arm STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties(
  someLib_arm
  PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE "path/to/arm/libsomeLib.a"
)

target_link_libraries(
  someLib
  INTERFACE
    someLib_x64
    someLib_arm
)
```

This seems to result in a valid compilation for both architectures (building for "Any Mac (Apple Silicon, Intel)"), however it causes a bunch of linker warnings as each architecture complains about the other one.

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /path/to/x64/libsomeLib.a, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
```

and vice versa.

What is a more accurate way to do this that avoids linker warnings? I couldn't find an applicable generator expression to change the link path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited, I misunderstood this previously. I think you have 3 options

- suppress error, the error doesn't affect anything in fact, so the simplist way to

```
add_link_option("-w")
```

to ignore it, or just change link option for the target

- try the latest cmake concept [`IMPORTED_TARGET`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_OBJECTS.html?highlight=universal%20library), it looks like perfectly fit your demand, but require new cmake version
- try to compile an universal library from source code, this is some example
  [change flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350107/how-to-compile-universal-libraries-on-mac-os-x) or [cmake official example](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling-for-ios-tvos-or-watchos), but this looks like need another project for source code of the lib

---

UPDATE: ACCEPTED ANSWER:
Based on the documentation for `IMPORTED_TARGET` linked here, it revealed that you can use the symbol `$(CURRENT_ARCH)` in the library path, which is interpreted by Xcode at link time.

Works perfectly.

Comment: so the issue is `CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES` is the value `x86_64;arm64`. Therefore your example will not link the x64 binaries. If you have an actual example with generator expressions I think that will be the better way even though its harder to read as you say

Comment: @yano, sorry I misunderstood previously

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the two .a files into the fat binary and use the combined library for compilation. The linker will select the correct version based on the architecture.

To combine the .a library files, you can use the `lipo` command:

```
lipo -create 'path/to/x64/libsomeLib.a' 'path/to/arm/libsomeLib.a' \
     -output 'path/to/combined/libsomeLib.a'
```

The combined library file can be reused until you need to install an update to the library. Alternatively, you can create a aggregate target to combine the library files every time you compile if you prefer not to manage the library manually.

Comment: this is also a good solution, but would require to pre-process the third party library, so I went with the other solution which is easier to maintain.